# how can i update the addition of two numbers on a same feild of a mongoodb document in mongoosejs

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, addition

OK,so i am tring to make a accoounting website which have two collection "Entries"and"Users"

the user schema is--

```html
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    require: true,
    unique: true,
    trim: true,
    max: 20,
    min: 3,
  },
  fbalance: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0,
  },
  cbalance: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0,
  },
});
```

here is the "entry schema"--

```html
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  receivername: {
    type: String,
    require: true,
    unique: true,
    trim: true,
    max: 20,
    min: 3,
  },
  price: {
    type: Number,
    require: true,
    default: 0,
  },
  product: {
    type: String,
    required:true
  },
});
```

so,what i want to do is that whenever i post a entry for sell i want to update the "cbalance" and add the price of the product to the "cbalance" of the user but i can't **ADD** the price to the "cbalance" instead it is just repracing the "price" value to "cbalance" value.

prease tell me if there is a way to perform $add operation while updating the document in mongoose.

Comment: What you can do is use pre-update hook in entry schema to update data in userSchema when you are updating entry

Comment: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that can be one way of doing it, but have figured out the solution for my situation, I am just going to use the $inc operator in query while updating the document